# Save scanned vCard to windows phone contacts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have implemented a code where I get the vCard information by scanning a QR Code, but I;m unable to save it to my phone contacts.

Thanking everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the [SaveContactTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394013(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: thanks for the response, i got it done with another approach!!